# Can I memoize retroactively?

Tags: memoization

I have a function defined something like this:

```
f[x_] := Module[...];
```

I can easily write a memoized version of it like this:

```
f2[x_] := f2[x] = f[x];
```

And then replace every instance of `f[...]` with `f2[...]` in my code.

However, I have code that uses `f` directly in many places (the actual situation is more complicated: I have several such functions that call each other).

Can I retroactively memoize f? Something like this:

```
(* set ftemp to the original version of f *)
ftemp = f;
(* memoize the original f *)
f[x_] := f[x] = ftemp[x];
```

This (and several variants) don't work, probably because `f` is defined as `:=` and `=` (ie, it's evaluated when called).

When I do `?f`, I see the definition of `f`. If I could somehow copy this to `ftemp`, I think my trick above would work.

Any thoughts on how I could do this and/or solve the general problem of memoizing retroactively?

Comment: So you are saying just `f[x_] := f[x] = ...' wouldn't work? I'm confused about the meaning of "retroactively" here. Memoization after what? You mean in a running session?

Comment: I only want to memoize `f` in a specific file. I don't want to rewrite the definition of `f` in the file where it's defined. Normally, I would use `f` without memoization, but, in this one special case, I want to memoize.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand... You are saying you want to switch on memoization on the fly?

Comment: ...because when you say you want to use memoization only "in a specific file" I would suggest to just use the definition of `f2` from your post...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
f[x_] := x^2

DownValues[h] = DownValues[f] /. f -> h;
f[x_] := f[x] = h[x]
```

`h` is now equal to the original `f`, and `f` is a memoized version of it.

Some kinds of definitions would require a more specific replacement rule than `/. f -> h`, for example recursive functions.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! I was messing around with things like Definition[] but couldn't quite get it to work.